# Delphi XE7 XML Documentation

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, xml-documentation

In Delphi XE2, there was an IDE feature which allowed me to create in-line XML code documentation (following Microsoft standards) in an editor window. It would describe each class, type, method, etc. in the `interface` section of a unit. However, in Delphi XE7, I cannot find it. I've done some searching, but as you can imagine, `Delphi XE7 XML Code Documentation` does not return the results I'm looking for.

In XE2, I remember the shortcut to toggle this window was either `CTRL + SHIFT + D` or `CTRL + ALT + D`. Neither of them do anything in XE7. I know I could manually write this myself, but that's a bit inconvenient. All I can find in the documentation is how to write the text yourself, and nothing about the editor window I was used to in XE2. I never installed any Delphi add-ons other than what came with Delphi itself (besides IDE Fix Pack).

Where can I find this feature in Delphi XE7 Enterprise? Or was it removed for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you are describing is not directly implemented into Delphi but comes as third party addon that does integrate into Delphi. It is called Documentation Insight.

http://www.devjetsoftware.com/products/documentation-insight/

Documentation insight had come as free third party addon till Delphi XE6 when it was suposingly removed. Don't ask me why as I don't know.

So I'm afraid that you will have to buy this third party IDE extention now.

EDIT: Or you could use newest version of Delphi for development of your program and older version of Delphi like XE2 to generate documentation.

Comment: Perfect, another reason people don't seem to like Delphi :-) I'll just bear with writing it myself - the IDE still recognizes it and shows it in the code editor when hovering over things. For the record I stumbled across it one day, when going to hit `CTRL + SHIFT + S` to save all I accidentally hit `D` and this window popped up, so I used it.

Comment: I myself actually never used this feature but I knew it existed. Well to be perfectly hones I haven't done any documentation writing for nay of my source code yet.